# read write locks on sqlite

Tags: c++, ios, c, swift, sqlite

the question is already clear, the one who marked it as not clear needs to go and clear his understanding first. People commending under understood it.

Any advanced Sqlite pro who's familiar with read write locks (mutex) using given sqlite constructs or essentially handle Read/Write Concurrency or race conditions.

I'm tagging C as well since its a mixture of Swift + C code.

Are there such constructs that can let **read happen concurrently** but then locks all reading threads **when write is happening**. (There are of course some constructs provided by iOS like serial queues etc. but I'm interested in utilities offered by sqlite)

I've one Read and one Write operation in the following example.

Q. How to implement concurrency across both read write operations so read can happen concurrently and will be blocked on write and will wait on the write to finish.

```
var database: OpaquePointer! // DI populates database connection

// read operation
func getDepartments() throws -> [Department]? { 

    sqlite3_mutex_enter(sqlite3_db_mutex(database))

    var statement: OpaquePointer? = nil
    let sql = "SELECT * FROM department"
    
    guard sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK else {
        throw NSError(domain: String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(database)), code: 1, userInfo: nil)
    }
    
    defer {
        sqlite3_finalize(statement)
        sqlite3_mutex_leave(sqlite3_db_mutex(database))
    }
    
    var departments: [Department] = []
    while sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW {
        departments.append(Department(id: sqlite3_column_int64(statement, 0), name: String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1))))
    }
    return departments
}


// write operation, needs lock
func delete(_ id: Int32) throws -> Int32? { 
    let sql = "DELETE FROM department WHERE id = \(id)"
    
    guard sqlite3_exec(database, sql, nil, nil, nil) == SQLITE_OK else {
        throw NSError(domain: String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(database)), code: 2, userInfo: nil)
    }
    
    return sqlite3_changes(database)
}
```

---

This returns 2 -> `print(sqlite3_threadsafe())`

Comment: I would consider Sqlite [transactions](https://sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) first, before arbitrarily attempting application-level "locks" and "mutexes".  You should also read up on  [Isolation](https://sqlite.org/isolation.html)

Comment: thanks for the insights on the transactions, I can see its one of the methods, but still I'm looking for `sqlite3_mutex_try` or `sqlite3_mutex_enter` approach. btw in context of isolation I'm using single db connection for all CRUD calls

Comment: Experience has shown me that the only sane way to use sqlite and threads is for each thread to have its own independent connection to the database in what sqlite calls [mult-thread mode](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html) (Unless you're only ever reading from the db and never writing, in which case serialized mode is fine). And, yes, rely on transactions for access control.

Comment: I see, what's the use of `sqlite3_mutex_enter` or `sqlite3_mutex_try` then?

Comment: @Shawn with that answer, is it okay that every CRUD operation I have will `sqlite3_open` statement, now coming from a different language background, people looking at my code would say, that's in efficient. I'm going to implement this way but wanted to hear your thoughts on this.

Comment: Shawn, please add it as your answer and if possible with more explanations. Regards.